# C++ printing correctly to terminal but not to output file

Tags: c++, io, ostream

Beginner c++ coder, and can't seem to figure out this bug.

I'm trying to print 256 numbers on individual lines to an output file. This seems to work most of the time. However, when all 256 numbers are `0`, it instead prints 256 `ਰ` characters on the same line. If I print `2 0's` on the same line, it works perfectly, and if I remove the next-line, it also works perfectly.

I tried flushing the ostream, but that did not help. I thought it might be an issue with unsigned int, but casting and `to_string()` also did not help. The code prints perfectly to terminal, but not to file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
vector<unsigned int> freqs(256);

ofstream outfile(outFileName);

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    outfile << freqs[i];
    outfile << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `endl` operator. `endl` makes a newline like `\n` but is not platform specific.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<unsigned int> freqs(256);

    ofstream fileToWriteTo;
    fileToWriteTo.open("file.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        fileToWriteTo << freqs.at(i) << endl;
    }

    fileToWriteTo.close();

}
```

Edit: This code below ran for me perfectly fine. What are you using to compile? (By fine, I mean it created a file with 256 0s on different lines)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<unsigned int> freqs(256);

    ofstream outfile("outFileName.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        outfile << freqs[i];
        outfile << '\n';
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Morgan, thank you for the response, what is your suggested change exactly? I have tried using endl as well, to no avail.

Comment: How are you populating the vector? Also, Maybe try to use the .at(i) too just to see. Not quite sure why your codes not working based on whats given.

Comment: std::endl writes '\n' to the output stream, and then flushes the stream. This flush would be performed by the dtor of the file stream. Whilst it may widen '\n' to a unicode character, it will not insert '\r'. Try using "\r\n" instead. (Or better yet, use a better text editor than notepad! e.g. textpad, notepad++, etc). Worth noting that std::endl is far slower than '\n', and isn't something that's really needed when writing to a file.

Comment: The vector is populated with by scanning through a input text file, and freqs[char]++ for each char in the file. However, running this with most input files works fine, but the edge case of an empty file, where the vector contains only 0's does not work. I also tried .at(i), which also did not work.

Comment: @robthebloke this seems to have worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: I think \r is not needed for some systems, is that correct? When i run on linux it was not needed. And it has given my problems before going from windows to linux for a school project.

Comment: @Morgan maybe that is the issue, I am on a windows. I'm using a meson build system along with ninja. I am not familiar with either, they were assigned by my class.

Comment: linux/macos use "\n". Windows uses "\r\n", but only in the crappy text editors like notepad. textpad or notepad++ won't have this problem.